# Group by and Order by in horizontal presentation

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have an SQL statement as follows:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    fld01, 
    fld02,
    fld03 AS AGENT,
    fld04 AS DIGIT,
    COUNT(*) AS fld05 AS OCCURRENCE
FROM table AS BaseView
GROUP BY fld03
ORDER BY fld03, fld05  DESC, fld04
```

My returned result always in 10 rows, which is from 0 to 9 (for the returned result grouped by fld03), with number of count(*) as number of occurrence for the returned result.

Therefore, my returned result should be always as follows:

```
fld01 | fld02 | fld03 (AGENT) | fld04 (DIGIT) | fld05 (OCCURRENCE)

XX    | YY    | AGENT1        | 0             | 16
XX    | YY    | AGENT1        | 4             | 15
XX    | YY    | AGENT1        | 6             | 12
XX    | YY    | AGENT1        | 7             | 10
XX    | YY    | AGENT1        | 1             | 9
XX    | YY    | AGENT1        | 9             | 9
XX    | YY    | AGENT1        | 3             | 8
XX    | YY    | AGENT1        | 5             | 7
XX    | YY    | AGENT1        | 2             | 4
XX    | YY    | AGENT1        | 8             | 2
```

My Issue is:

I would like my returned result to be displayed as horizontal presentation (order by number of count in DESC mode).

Which expected returned result as follows:

```
fld01 | fld02 | fld03  | D01 | D02 | D03 | D04 | D05 | D06 | D07 | D08 | D09 | D10

XX    | YY    | AGENT1 | 0   | 4   | 6   | 7   | 1   | 9   | 3   | 5   | 2   | 8
```

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks as fld01 and fld02, are the same for all values of fld03 and so realistically they should be in a seperate table.  You label the table as BaseView so it is possible that this is already the case.  Please be aware that the following example query assumes the above to be true (that fld01, fld02, and fld03 are always the same for each value of fld03)

Additionally this feels nasty - this is really a job for output rather than for this stage of data selection.  I would not do things this way in my systems.

```
SELECT
    -- base values
    baseView.ID,
    baseView.fld01,
    baseView.fld02,
    baseView.fld03,

    -- counts from the various tables
    COALESCE(COUNT(d01.fld03),0) AS d01,
    COALESCE(COUNT(d02.fld03),0) AS d02,
    COALESCE(COUNT(d03.fld03),0) AS d03,
    COALESCE(COUNT(d04.fld03),0) AS d04,
    COALESCE(COUNT(d05.fld03),0) AS d05,
    COALESCE(COUNT(d06.fld03),0) AS d06,
    COALESCE(COUNT(d07.fld03),0) AS d07,
    COALESCE(COUNT(d08.fld03),0) AS d08,
    COALESCE(COUNT(d09.fld03),0) AS d09,
    COALESCE(COUNT(d10.fld03),0) AS d10

FROM table AS baseView
LEFT JOIN table AS d01
    ON d01.fld03 = baseView.fld03
    AND d01.fld04 = 1
LEFT JOIN table AS d02
    ON d02.fld03 = baseView.fld03
    AND d02.fld04 = 2
LEFT JOIN table AS d03
    ON d03.fld03 = baseView.fld03
    AND d03.fld04 = 3
LEFT JOIN table AS d04
    ON d04.fld03 = baseView.fld03
    AND d04.fld04 = 4
LEFT JOIN table AS d05
    ON d05.fld03 = baseView.fld03
    AND d05.fld04 = 5
LEFT JOIN table AS d06
    ON d06.fld03 = baseView.fld03
    AND d06.fld04 = 6
LEFT JOIN table AS d07
    ON d07.fld03 = baseView.fld03
    AND d07.fld04 = 7
LEFT JOIN table AS d08
    ON d08.fld03 = baseView.fld03
    AND d08.fld04 = 8
LEFT JOIN table AS d09
    ON d09.fld03 = baseView.fld03
    AND d09.fld04 = 9
LEFT JOIN table AS d10
    ON d10.fld03 = baseView.fld03
    AND d10.fld04 = 0

GROUP BY baseView.fld03
ORDER BY fld03
```

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks for your answers.  I am not sure what is your suggestion. ... If you read carefully, ... My returned result always in 10 rows, which is from 0 to 9 (for the returned result grouped by fld03), with number of count(*) as number of occurrence for the returned result.

My Issue is:

I would like my returned result to be displayed as horizontal presentation (order by number of count in DESC mode).

Comment: Please provide a sample data set of 5-10 rows, along with a sample output.  This will help clarify precisely what you are looking for, as I am still struggling to determine your precise aim.  Please do this by editing your question, so that others may easily find this additional information.

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks in advance :).  I have added example by editing my questions.

Comment: Wow, ok, there's not as simple a way to achieve that really without using a lot of LEFT JOINs!